# Pull request's comments list are not coming by using Azure DevOps rest api

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using Azure DevOps rest api for getting all the comments of the every pull request. I have go through Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20thread%20comments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). I followed same. But when i see my json response, it does not show list of comments. it is getting following result as i fire get request.

official url given in documentation

https://dev.azure.com/myorg/_apis/git/repositories/jd7489eiu-e5bb-37f7-kl05-098kd4dd/pullRequests/192/threads/{threadId}/comments?api-version=5.1"

I tried following urls for acheive my result
https://dev.azure.com/myorg/_apis/git/repositories/jd7489eiu-e5bb-37f7-kl05-098kd4dd/pullRequests/192/threads?api-version=5.1"

returning comments are empty

```
{
   "pullRequestThreadContext":  null,
   "id":  1341,
   "publishedDate":  "2019-02-05T13:15:20.903Z",
   "lastUpdatedDate":  "2019-02-05T13:15:20.903Z",
   "comments":  "",
   "threadContext":  null,
   "properties":  "@{BypassPolicy=; BypassReason=; CodeReviewStatus=; CodeReviewStatusUpdateAssociatedCommit=; CodeReviewThreadType=; CodeReviewStatusUpdatedByIdentity=}",
   "identities":  "@{1=}",
   "isDeleted":  false,
   "_links":  "@{self=; repository=}"
}
```

https://dev.azure.com/myorg/_apis/git/repositories/jd7489eiu-e5bb-37f7-kl05-098kd4dd/pullRequests/192/threads/131/comments?api-version=5.1"

Above url is returning same result as above.

https://dev.azure.com/myorg/_apis/git/repositories/jd7489eiu-e5bb-37f7-kl05-098kd4dd/pullRequests/192/threads/131?api-version=5.1"

returning comments are empty

```
{
   "pullRequestThreadContext":  null,
   "id":  1341,
   "publishedDate":  "2019-02-05T13:15:20.903Z",
   "lastUpdatedDate":  "2019-02-05T13:15:20.903Z",
   "comments":  "",
   "threadContext":  null,
   "properties":  "@{BypassPolicy=; BypassReason=; CodeReviewStatus=; CodeReviewStatusUpdateAssociatedCommit=; CodeReviewThreadType=; CodeReviewStatusUpdatedByIdentity=}",
   "identities":  "@{1=}",
   "isDeleted":  false,
   "_links":  "@{self=; repository=}"
}
```

**Did anyone facing the same problem, or know the solution please let me know.**

Comment: I assume the PR status you are getting with API is completed, right? Because the properties `BypassPolicy` and `BypassReason` and etc only exists in the **completed** PR. As you said its comment are empty, did you mean there's nothing in it? Include without some parameters list in it, such as parentCommentId or commentType?  If yes, could you update with the screenshots in your question? In addition, what about see the comment with web UI.

Comment: below one from your question should work... but i noticed that you have "131" as your threadId in the link you provided, supposed to be 1341 from the response you mentioned.

https://dev.azure.com/myorg/_apis/git/repositories/jd7489eiu-e5bb-37f7-kl05-098kd4dd/pullRequests/192/threads/1341/comments?api-version=5.1"